# Using Riemann sums to approximate area under the curve $y = 1/x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

This was the question I was given:

*Use a Riemann sum with n = 5 rectangles to approximate the area of the region bounded by the lines $x = 1$, $x = 2$, $y = 0$ and the curve $y = 1/x$. Use the appropriate endpoint of each subinterval to compute a lower sum.*

When I saw this problem, this is what I came up with: $$\sum^n_{i=0} \frac51\frac1x \Delta x$$

However, this did not result in the right answer. Where did I go wrong when finding the Riemann Sum? How can I rectify this?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Do you know how $x$ depends on $i$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Note:  I don't know why you wrote $\dfrac51$; that does not belong

Comment: What I mean is this:  when you compute that sum you wrote, there is a different value of $x$ for each $i$; if I tell you a particular value of $i$, can you tell me what is the value of $x$ corresponding to that $i$?

Comment: Note:  if $i$ goes from $\color{red}0$ to $n$, that’s $n\color{red}{+1}$ rectangles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower Riemann sum would be $$\sum_{i=1}^5 \dfrac 1{ x} \Delta x$$ with $\Delta x=\dfrac15$ and $x=1+i\Delta x$.

In other words, $\dfrac15\left(\dfrac1{1.2}+\dfrac1{1.4}+\dfrac1{1.6}+\dfrac1{1.8}+\dfrac12\right)$.

Comment: so to figure out $\Delta x$ you divide 5 by 1?

Comment: Or did I just pull that out of nowhere?

Comment: The width of each rectangle is $\dfrac15=\dfrac{2-1}5$; we're dividing the region between $x=1$ and $x=2$ into $5$ equal sub-intervals

Comment: So I just did it backwards

Comment: The $\Delta x$ is $\dfrac15$; as I commented above, $\dfrac51$ does not belong there

Comment: more subtle point:  $\dfrac1x$ is decreasing in this interval, so I'm taking the least $x$ in each subinterval to get the **lower** sum; for example, in the first sub-interval I take $x=1.2$ rather than $x=1$

Comment: How do I figure out what $\Delta x$ is?

Comment: Oh, I see - its $\frac{b-a}n$

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to discuss Riemann sums in pictures. Here's the region whose area we are supposed to approximate:
[image]
You need to use $5$ rectangles. This means that you should subdivide the domain into $5$ equal pieces:
[image]
Next, we draw perpendicular lines up to the graph, ready to become the sides of rectangles:
[image]
Now, we we need to choose the height of the rectangles. We want the *lower* sums, hence we want the height of the rectangles to be as small as possible. As this is a decreasing function, the height of the rectangle will therefore be the function value at the *rightmost* point of its base, giving us our final picture:
[image]
These are our final five rectangles. If we compute the area of these rectangles, and sum them up, this will be our Riemann sum. Our rectangles all have a width of $0.2$. Their respective heights are $\frac{1}{1.2}, \frac{1}{1.4}, \frac{1}{1.6}, \frac{1}{1.8},$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, the Riemann sum is:

> $$0.2 \cdot \frac{1}{1.2} + 0.2 \cdot \frac{1}{1.4} + 0.2 \cdot \frac{1}{1.6} + 0.2 \cdot \frac{1}{1.8} + 0.2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.65.$$

Comment: Pictures are very helpful for this (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The width is going to be the same for all of the five rectangles (it's basically the length of the interval, which is $1$, divided by $5$):
$$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{2-1}{5}=\frac{1}{5}.$$

A sample point on the interval $[1,2]$: $$x_i=a+i\cdot \Delta x=1+\frac{i}{5}.$$

You get the area under the curve (in this case, it's going to be an approximation, of course) by multiplying the height of a rectangle, which is your function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ evaluated at the sample point $x_i$, by the width $\Delta x=\frac{1}{5}$, which is the same for all of the five rectangles:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{5}f(x_i)\Delta x=
\sum_{i=1}^{5}\frac{1}{1+\frac{i}{5}}\frac{1}{5}=\\
\sum_{i=1}^{5}\frac{1}{5+i}=\frac16+\frac17+\frac18+\frac19+\frac{1}{10}\approx 0.65.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone knows how to use upper or lower sums when x --> infinity for 1/x  function? I was using summation formula but I got stuck when it comes to sum 0f 1/n+i

Comment: This is not an answer